# C++ returning pointer from function. Values are lost

Tags: c++, pointers

I have the the following:

```
void Class1::method()
{
  QStringList* file_list;
  collect_file_paths(file_list);    //Sends pointer to the method below
}

void Class1::collect_file_paths(QStringList* file_list)
{
  //Gather file paths
  DirectorySearch ds;
  connect(&ds, SIGNAL(updateStatus(QString)), this, SLOT(onStatusUpdate(QString)));
  file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);  //Returns a pointer of QStringList
}

QStringList* DirectorySearch::get_file_names(QString path)
{
  QStringList *file_names = new QStringList;
  traverse(path, file_names);
  compare_existing(file_names);
  return file_names;  //returning pointer address
}
```

What is happening is that the memory address returned from `get_file_names()` is lost/deleted when I leave the scope of `Class1::collect_file_paths()`.  It was my understanding that `QStringList *file_names = new QStringList;` in the DirectorySearch class in now on the memory heap.  So it should be left on the heap until I call `delete` i.e. it is never out of scope.  However, as mentioned above, the address/values of the `QStingList` are lost when I return to `Class1::method()` from `collect_file_paths(file_list)`.

Can some explain what is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you do `file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);  //Returns a pointer of QStringList`
 you are changing the value of the `file_list` (a 32/64b memory location) NOT the value of the data that memory location represents.

You need to pass a reference to your pointer (or a pointer to a pointer)

```
void Class1::method()
{
  QStringList* file_list;
  collect_file_paths(&file_list);    //Sends pointer to pointer to the method below
}

void Class1::collect_file_paths(QStringList** file_list)
{
  //Gather file paths
  DirectorySearch ds;
  connect(&ds, SIGNAL(updateStatus(QString)), this, SLOT(onStatusUpdate(QString)));
  *file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath); //set value of pointer in caller to value returned by below function
}
...
```

or so

Comment: In your opinion, would you use pointers in this away?  I've been looking at textbooks this afternoon trying to find more information about passing pointers in the way of method(<type>** var_name){}, but I haven't found anything yet.  I'd like some advice on how more experienced programmers would approach my problem above/what would they change in the code.

Comment: I prefer to use a pointer to a pointer ( `int **var` ) rather than a reference to a pointer ( `int *&var` ). If you do a Google search for 'pointer to pointer' some good stuff ought to come up. Also http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=pointer+to+pointer

Answer (score 2):

Your `collect_file_paths` method does not modify the file_list pointer in any way that's visible.  When `collect_file_paths` is called, it is given a memory address (pointer) of a QStringList.  If you were to assign to the `file_list` variable, you would simply be pointing to a different `QStringList`, but the callers cannot see this.

It is as if you wrote the following:

```
void foo(int a)
{
  /* Callers will not see this change. */
  a = 5;
}
```

What you need to do is pass a pointer to the pointer:

```
void collect_file_paths(QStringList **file_list)
{
  *file_list = ...
}

void foo()
{
  QStringList *file_names;
  collect_file_paths(&file_names);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `get_file_names()` method is fine. Your problem is the `collect_file_paths()`. The `file_list` pointer is *copied* into the function, so assigning to it within `collect_file_paths` has no effect on `file_list` variable within the `method`.

One option is to use a reference to a pointer:

```
void Class1::collect_file_paths(QStringList*& file_list) ...
```

Or, as others suggest, just pass around reference to the list itself and act on that.

Answer (score 1):

The comment:

```
  collect_file_paths(file_list);    //Sends pointer to the method below
```

is wrong: The call copies the pointer to the method arguments.

So the line:

```
file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);  //Returns a pointer of QStringList
```

Does nothing to the value in the `method()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the result via a reference:

```
void Class1::collect_file_paths(QStringList& file_list)
{
  //Gather file paths
  DirectorySearch ds;
  connect(&ds, SIGNAL(updateStatus(QString)), this, SLOT(onStatusUpdate(QString)));
  file_list = ds.get_file_names(_strPath);  //Returns a pointer of QStringList
}
```